# emacs line wrapping and numbering

Tags: emacs, xubuntu, numbering

How can I tell emacs to wrap lines at the 80th character?

I am looking for a solution I can put in `/.emacs`.

I put this in `/.emacs` but it doesn't work.

```
;; ========== Enable Line Numbering ==========                                         

(line-number-mode 1)

;; ========== Set the fill column ==========                                           

(setq-default fill-column 80)
```

Comment: `fill-column` controls paragraph reformatting (`M-q`, similar to Vim's `gqap`) and the automatic replacement of inserted spaces by (`auto-fill-mode`, similar to Vim's `textwidth` (I think)). Is that what you wanted? Or did you mean on-screen wrapping that doesn't affect the content of the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's a typographical error?

It should be

```
 
(setq default-fill-column 80)
```

Comment: No, that's deprecated but equivalent to `(setq-default fill-column 80)`.